Integrate a custom form with Stripe
I need to replicate the exact behaviour for this donation form:
https://hopeandhomes.ro/doneaza/
It collects some data and then redirects to a Stripe Checkout.
I can see the logic of the frontend, but I don't know how the backend works. Or what is needed. I'm a complete noob :)
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck? Do you have any specific question about this?

you can take a look at https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment and https://docs.stripe.com/checkout/quickstart for reference
